# need to create an efficient index for a table with more than 2 million records

Tags: mysql, drupal

the query that i need to optimize is the following:

```
 SELECT  field0.entity_type AS entity_type,
                field0.entity_id AS entity_id, field0.revision_id AS revision_id,
                field0.bundle AS bundle
            FROM  field field0
            INNER JOIN  node node  ON node.nid = field0.entity_id
            WHERE  (field0.field_value = '23ad')
              AND  (field0.deleted = '0')
              AND  (node.status = '1')
              AND  (field0.entity_type = 'node')
              AND  (field0.bundle = 'title')
```

the below part of the query is always the same:

```
AND  (field0.deleted = '0')
          AND  (node.status = '1')
          AND  (field0.entity_type = 'node')
          AND  (field0.bundle = 'title')
```

The only line that changes is this:

```
WHERE  (field0.field_value = '?')
```

Follows the explain result of the above query:

[explain select result][1]

and the result of the SHOW INDEXES from  field query:

[result of existing indexes in table named field][2]

Not only do i have this huge table, but since this db belongs to a drupal 7 site, there are many more tables, so the performance is really slow.
Which index would you suggest i make? and what should i do with the existing indexes?

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` returns 5.7.29

[result of SHOW INDEXES from  node;][3]

[result of DESCRIBE node;][4]

[result of DESCRIBE field;][5]

i tested below answer, and it differs from my first trial:
(bundle, entity_type, deleted, field_tl_uuid_value,                             entity_id, revision_id). Both give me results, which should i choose and why?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfcn6.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXsPt.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w9lD.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTRDY.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvRVX.png

Comment: What are the primary keys of each table? What other keys, or indexes do the tables have?

Comment: I have added some info that may be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would benefit from the following index:

```
create index on field (bundle, entity_type, deleted, field_value);
```

Comment: i tested the above answer, and it differs from my first trial:
(bundle, entity_type, deleted, field_tl_uuid_value,                             entity_id, revision_id). Both give me results, which should i choose and why?

Comment: @jageyaj820 As a general rule, each index you add to a table has a cost when inserting, updating, and deleting, Keep a minimum number of indexes that you need (I would avoid going avoid 10 indexes per table). Now, both indexes include the "filtering columns" so they should provide similar results. I would choose the smallest one (less columns, smaller columns), since it would be cheaper for the engine.